# How can I prevent rollup from leaving an import statement to a external library in the bundle?

Tags: rollupjs

I have such web app:

- typescript code
- rollup as bundler
- mapboxgl as an external library
- use es6 modules
- produce a single bundle.js holding all typescript files but not the mapboxgl code which is referenced with a separate script tag

All is fine, the only problem is that the bundle.js includes a wrong

```
import { Map } from 'mapbox-gl';
// why is this import here, although rollup.config declares mapbox-gl external?

... bundle code follows as expected
```

at its head.

rollup.config.js:

```
export default {
    input: './js/app.tsx',
    output: [
        {
            file: 'dist/bundle.js',
            format: 'es'
        },
    ],
    external: ['mapbox-gl'], // this should prevent imports from mapbox-gl in the bundle
    plugins: [
        typescript()
    ],
}
```

I searched all stackoverflow and through endless github repos but that did not reveal why this import statement is left. I opened a feature request in rollup to allow plain js bundle creation, as I believe that rollup is correct as it assumed that the bundle is used as a module - for format is set to "es" in the end.

https://github.com/rollup/rollup/issues/3868

Comment: Did you ever find a clean solution to this?  Right now, I'm stripping these out of my bundle with sed, but I'd prefer a cleaner way to do it.

Comment: AFAIR i still use string replacement in that project. The issue above was not handled. The best thing might be fixing rollup and creating a pull request. Since rollup continues like as the base of vite (my now favorite tool) that would make good sense.

Comment: I am now using Vite as well.  Here is the solution that I settled on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74723484/how-to-get-vite-to-not-import-bundle-an-external-dependency/74723564

Comment: Have you tried using `@rollup/plugin-node-resolve`?

Comment: @GavHern I used node-resolve for resolving in the way node does, but do not see how that solves the problem here.

Comment: @citykid i suggested it since i had the same issue and it was fixed by using that plugin.

Comment: thx for the hint, once i come back to that project i take a look at that.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem. `@rollup/plugin-node-resolve` fixed it.

Rollup will not find and bundle Node dependencies by default. By default, Rollup follows the vanilla ES Module specification which knows nothing about Node.js dependencies inside of node_modules. Adding this plugin makes Rollup look for packages in node_modules and hence it will no longer consider them "external" and will bundle them instead of considering them to be external.

OP: You don't want mapbox to be "external". In Rollup's perspective, an "external" module is a module that will *not* be included in your bundle. In your case, mapbox *already is* external, but you want to make it internal to (included in) your bundle, which is what this plugin does.