# How to get Vite to not import/bundle an external dependency

Tags: typescript, vite

I have several libraries that I am forced to include via `<script>` tags.  I would still, however, like to use the equivalent import statements in my .ts for those external libraries, so that I get proper typing.  How do I tell Vite to not bundle those particular imports, and expunge the import statements for those?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is much harder than it should be, but I finally found a way to ignore externally-included libraries in my bundle thanks to the [rollup-plugin-hypothetical](https://github.com/lemmabit/rollup-plugin-hypothetical/issues/6) plugin and a specific fork of the  [rollup-plugin-postprocess](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@stadtlandnetz/rollup-plugin-postprocess) plugin.  Rollup plugins are compatible with Vite.  The *hypothetical* plugin removes the code from the bundle, and *postprocess* plugin allows you to remove the imports from the bundle via regex.  Note that I am removing all imports -- if you only need to remove some then your *postprocess* regex will differ.

Install the plugins with npm:

```
npm install --save-dev rollup-plugin-hypothetical
npm install --save-dev @stadtlandnetz/rollup-plugin-postprocess
```

Example vite.config.js with the 3 node modules I wanted to exclude:

```
// vite.config.js

import hypothetical from 'rollup-plugin-hypothetical';
import postprocess from '@stadtlandnetz/rollup-plugin-postprocess';

export default {
    build: {
        rollupOptions: {
            external: ['masonry-layout', 'typeahead-standalone', 'video.js']
        }
    },
    plugins: [
        hypothetical({
            allowFallthrough: true,
            files: {
                'typeahead-standalone/': ``,
                'masonry-layout/': ``,
                'video.js/': ``
            }
        }),
        postprocess([
            [/import[^;]*/, '']
        ])
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this useful link and explanation. It seems like the ideal thing might be to pre-process the files and simply remove the import. This would make the ‘hypothetical’ step unnecessary. Though I’m not sure if a vite plug-in exists to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the types from an `import`, then you should use `import type` instead. That was introduced in [Typescript 3.8](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-8.html). Importing only the types should prevent the bundling of any actual code.

```
import type { Counter } from './Counter';

declare global {
  interface Window {
    ExternalCounter: typeof Counter;
  }
}

// Then `ExternalCounter` will be a fully typed interface to the Counter class
```

[Here is a full example on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-51dy7y?file=index.html,src%2FCounter.ts,src%2Fmain.ts,package.json&terminal=dev). I used a script tag and then imported the class definition from a `.ts` file and used it.

Comment: While this is true, it doesn't help you with accessing functions or classes declared in the module, which would very likely be necessary in this scenario.

Comment: Not true. All you need is a handle to the class object or instance that has been cast to the correct type, as imported using `import type` (cast using the `as` operator). Then, everything will work.

Comment: I've added a StackBlitz example in case what I'm saying was not clear

Comment: That's actually my point.  I currently use the same gymnastics that you do for wrangling in classes and functions.  What I was saying is that import type alone does not solve the problem.  Adding this cruft would be unnecessary if the TypeScript folks actually cared about these fairly common use cases.  Also, in your StackBlitz, ExternalCounter is still not recognized by TS as a known class -- it has the red squiggly under it  (though in true JavaScript fashion, it still runs).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the error. I fixed the squiggly. The reason I still prefer my solution is that it is based on code only and would work with any build system. It doesn't require mucking with the Vite config.